# Is it possible to run FF3.x and FF4RC side by side?

Tags: firefox

As far as I know, mozilla firefox creates a directory in home folder/local settings in case of windows. So when I try to run firefox 4 rc and firefox 3.x only one is launched, is it possible to have these two run side bye side?

Comment: There's no reason to be using Firefox 4 RC1 or RC2; RC2 was renamed to final yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you may need to pass `-no-remote` in order to inhibit Firefox from opening another window from the existing instance instead of starting a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do it.  You can use the same profile (it will disable extensions, etc. if they're incompatible), or create multiple profiles.  See [this article](http://lifehacker.com/?_escaped_fragment_=231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles) and the [wiki](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles).

Comment: well this doesn't work for me, I am on Debian and my FF installations are in /opt and I created totally separate profile in totally separate folders, didnt work, the life hacker link doesn't work either

Comment: @Kumar, what doesn't work?  Did you just try just running `firefox -ProfileManager` (or firefox-4.0, whatever the case may be) and choosing?  If that works, you can then setup a shortcut.

Comment: For ff3.6 and ff4, I used `firefox -ProfileManager`, created profiles for both in totally separate folders, one by one, then launched FF4 & tried launching ff3, didnt work, note that in when I launched ff I used profile manager param, then I tried using `-no-remote`, didnt work either, now the issue is ff3.6 is set as my primary browser and I have tried all possible things to set chrome as my browser but it wont work either :(

Comment: @Kumar, you may need both ProfileManager and `-no-remote`.  Did you try them in combination?  As far the default browser, try [these instructions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Default_browser#Debian).

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it requires two things though.

1. Create a new profile like Matthew says
2. Pass `-no-remote` to `firefox` OR set `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1` (deprecated)

Comment: Have you tried it? I am on Debian and have tried it but it doesn't work, may be am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, Yes. Even if Firefox will only let you run one instance at a time, irrespective of the version number, then you can still get around it with third-party software which allows you to run more than one instance.

Try [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com).

Comment: sandboxie is for windoze, I cant even spell windoze correctly :P, but thanks, it will help others :)