# How do I run Firefox 4 and Firefox 3 at the same time on the same PC?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run FF3.x and FF4RC side by side?](https://superuser.com/questions/261296/is-it-possible-to-run-ff3-x-and-ff4rc-side-by-side)

Selenium is not compatible with FF4 and Firebug has some issues. I want to go back to FF3.6 but was wondering it is possible to run both 3.6 and 4 at the same time.

Comment: Two words: You don’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install firefox 3.6 after firefox 4 , and if you are still having issues install it on another drive

Answer (score 3):

Why not? Just simply use two profiles, or a portable Firefox 3, installed Firefox 4. Vica versa, portable Firefox 4 and installed Firefox 3.

The only thing that firefox can't stand is using the same profile.